# New Paypal Credential Not Found

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

Could not find the link to get paypal credential for live and test account. I have looked at the following page, but the page does not correspond with newly developed site.

```
          https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/cps/merchant/wppro/WPProIntegrationSteps-outside
```

Please help if you have any idea.. !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the details are here. 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Creating and Managing Classic API Credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/).

Comment: This is for the old PayPal, But new paypal has a different API. But it helped, Thanks anyway..